# Asp.net MVC3 Framework understanding the Idea Behind

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have tried to understand the MVC3 framework and when I used to start on a Project I Don't know that where I am starting the project what the arrangement of files And Why I am Adding Controllers Models As I am a Beginner somebody Please guide Me about its Structure of Solution Files and folder where we have To start  If Want something To make In this framework so What should I do For this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is a software architecture - the structure of the system - that separates domain/application/business (whatever you prefer) logic from the rest of the user interface. It does this by separating the application into three parts: the model, the view, and the controller.

Check this [ASP.NET MVC Overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/overview/asp-net-mvc-overview) .. It may clear you all doubt that what is Model , View and Controllers etc. First you learn about the MVC architechture, then look for the project.

spend few mintues learning these [Model-View-Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx), [What is MVC, really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127624/what-is-mvc-really), [Wiki - MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). It may help you to know about MVC project structure and interaction related stuff..

follow the Microsoft tutorial step by step.. There is much good tutorial named [MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store)

The best ASP.NET MVC tutorial I know is the NerdDinner application contained in "Professional ASP.NET MVC 3". It has been created by Scott Hanselman and is in production use online at http://www.NerdDinner.com.

[Free ASP.NET MVC eBook Tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx) , [Microsoft MVC Book or Tutorial Recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266126/microsoft-mvc-book-or-tutorial-recommendation)

Check recommended books for MVC 3.  I like `Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework` by Steven Sanderson.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315616/best-book-on-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: If you're going to use a paragraph from someone else's answer, you should quote it to make people aware that they're not your words.  Linking to that answer at a random place in your answer is not enough.  Credit where credit is due.

Comment: OHhh Yes Sir I am not going to make it an answer to elsewhere I just need Understanding therefore I Have joined the forum as this forum Getting Popularity.

Comment: @JohnH: mvc itself vast to tell anyone in few lines.. and regarding words of other: these are just two lines with my lines from the programmers website thread.

Comment: @NiranjanKala Yes I understand that, but you should *always* cite your sources directly.  It's simply bad form not to do so.

Comment: I want to move on in MVC could you please suggest me Next step.Thank you.

Comment: have you done any of tutorial above..  you have do things practically.. you can not do work on mvc without knowledge of partial view, controller mapping etc.. first do microsoft asp.net website tutorial then try to create you own small application with mvc on the basis of practical that you have done and take help on stackoverflow regarding problem that you face in doing your task..

Comment: Asp.net video tutorials I have watched 4 of the parts But I try to Implement the Examples Like OddToFood It is not Implemented becuase He  have made some Database files That I don't have So what Should I do If Go with him then I am not going To Implement anything but simple listening the tutorials cannot be Understood that What he is doing and It is Implemented.So If you have some More help guide me.I Just finished making MVC Music Store but in this example The huge code but no information that How code is working he Has used LINQ And I am getting out of it if Please do some help to me.

Comment: use these tutorial rather than using videos [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/movie-database/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs).. you can download northwind database from microsoft website..

Comment: Could You please tell me some more tutorials I have made it up Kindly tell me some more work in MVC3 or some useful links.Thank you.

Comment: could you give me some complete full fledged book to cover in MVC3.Thank you